# Where to download old versions of Advantage Database (Architect. Server...)

Tags: advantage-database-server

I'm wondering if there's a site where I can download older versions of the Advantage Database Server and the Advantage Database Architect.
On [this](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=16&Product=8&Platform=6) site only the newest version is avaialable.
Unfortunately, the new versions are often unstable or bring in new bugs, and so you are forced to downgrade to an older version.
Latest example: I just upgraded from Data Architect 10.10.0.6 to 10.10.0.17 and it wasn't possible anymore to create or modify triggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:
http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20

Version Matrix: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=31

Comment: Hi, I can download older major releases there, but only the last minor release for every major release. Or do I miss something?

Comment: which version do you need? 10.10.0.6?

Comment: Yes, 10.10.0.6. Thanks for the link to the matrix - missed this and google has no serch results to this site...

Comment: 10.10.0.6 is only avaiable for Linux there...any ideas where to download this version for windows?